# Invalid method declaration issue

Tags: java, syntax-error

Why am I getting an "invalid method declaration; return type required" error on **check(values);** ?

```
public class Swap
{
    int[] values = {5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    check(values);


    public void swapAdjacentElemnts(int[] values)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<values.length - 1; i+=2)
        {
            int tempInt = values[i];
            values[i] = values[i+1];
            values[i+1]=tempInt;
        }
    }

    public int[] check(int[] values)
    {
        swapAdjacentElements(values);
        return values;
    }
}
```

Comment: `check(values);` should be include in a method.

Comment: Or in a static block. But in that case, everything else would have to be static.

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to execute code outside of a method. Your call to `check` has to live inside of some kind of method, rather than in the class declaration.

If you meant for this to be in the constructor, you can do that:

```
public Swap()
{
    check(values);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put method calls on the class body directly.
That call should be inside another method (just like you do with `swapAdjacentElements`).

Maybe what you meant was to do the check inside the constructor of the class, or in a main method.

```
public class Swap
{
    int[] values = {5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    public Swap() { //class constructor
        check(values);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { //main method
        check(values);
    }

    //everything else..
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, You should execute a function, after other methods/functions are declared.